# Are misses in my data distributed completely at random?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a large data set containing children's scores on arithmetic tasks with a lot of missing values possibly due to the age of the children? My hypothesis is that the missingness is not completely at random but at random. I need to do a CFA and want to know whether I need to condition on age or not? I know SPSS 17 has a missing values analysis but my data is in R and is quite large. I would like to do a missing values analysis in R but have not been able to find a package that can do this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 14):

As @Dirk Eddelbuettel already mentioned, your questions is not very clear. In fact, I think you are asking two questions. The first question is related to your M(C)AR assumption. The second question is about (an) appropriate R package(s).

**(1) "Testing" for MAR**

To test if age has an effect on the missingness of your score variable, you could run a simple logistic regression model with age as a predictor variable. Your response variable is 0: score is not missing, 1: score is missing (see also @mbq's answer and @Macro's comment). Given the assumption that younger children are more likely to not report math scores, we expect to see a significant negative effect of age .

```
## Make up some data
set.seed(2)
## Younger children are more likely to not report math scores, 
## so I use a Poisson distribution to model that behaviour
missData <- rpois(10000, 10)
dfr <- data.frame(score=rnorm(100), age=sample(6:15, 100, replace=TRUE))
dfr <- dfr[order(dfr$age), ]
dfr$agemiss <- sort(sample(missData, 100, replace=TRUE))
dfr$miss <- ifelse(dfr$agemiss == dfr$age, 1, 0)                  

## Run the logistic regression with age as predictor
> summary(glm(miss ~ age, data=dfr, family=binomial))

[...]

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   5.9729     1.4946   3.996 6.43e-05 ***
age          -0.7997     0.1760  -4.544 5.53e-06 ***
---
[...]
```

**(2) (Some) Missing data related R packages**

Some of these packages also have functions to explore patterns of missingness (e.g., `missing.pattern.plot()` in the `mi` package).

- [Amelia II: A Program for Missing Data](http://gking.harvard.edu/amelia/)
- [Hmisc: Harrell Miscellaneous](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html)
- [mi: Missing Data Imputation and Model Checking](http://cran.us.r-project.org/web/packages/mi/index.html)
- [mitools: Tools for multiple imputation of missing data](http://cran.us.r-project.org/web/packages/mitools/index.html)

Comment: Interesting approach to `MCAR` testing! But what do you think about **alternatives**: *Little's test* for `MCAR` (http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2290157), implemented in `BaylorEdPsych` R package and *tests by Jamshidian and Jalal* (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v56/i06/paper), implemented in `MissMech` R package?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Thanks, I wasn't aware of those tests!

Comment: `mi::missing.pattern.plot()` looks like not available anymore.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I understand your question, you want to investigate if missing values in your data appear due to some pattern. In this case, you don't need any "missing value analysis" -- this is the same problem as checking whether the score is bigger than 0.7 or whatever. Just convert your dataset into two-class factor (missing, not-missing) and look for correlations.

Comment: BTW this is the method how people artificially proliferate functions in stuff like SPSS or SAS.

Comment: +1. Consider "missing" as a binary outcome and see if it is associated with any of the predictor variables using, for example, logistic regression. Not sure why CFA would be necessary. Like hammering a nail with a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little difficult to decipher.  One approach for dealing with missing data is [*imputation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_%28statistics%29) -- and there is a substantial literature on this and an already large and growing set of packages at [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) so you may want to start there.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. I see that my question was indeed not very clear. What I meant to ask was, Is the missing data completely at random (MCAR) and how do I do this in R. I t

Comment: The logistic regression seems to be an adequate method to test this. The reason that I won't to know the nature of the missing is because I'm performing a CFA on the complete data set (with missings) with FIML. However, if the missing is not MCAR but MAR then I would need to condition the latent variables on age (have age predict the latent variable arithmetic ability). Anyway, my problem is solved, thanks again. Cheers